# How to make nginx to send early data in POST method

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am testing TLS 1.3 and 0 RTT in a local nginx web server.

It works fine with `GET` methods. But when I use `POST` methods to send early data, it does not succeed. I think the cause is the ngnix server. I want to know how to enable nginx to support `POST` methods with early data.

Comment: While I consider this question potentially on-topic it is missing relevant information. With the given amount of detail it is impossible to reproduce or at least understand in full detail what you are trying. Not also that 0-RTT is vulnerable to replay attacks and should therefore only  be used for idempotent requests where a replay does not matter. POST request are not considered idempotent so whatever test client you use (again, your question does not provide sufficient details) might just refuse to use 0-RTT for POST for this reason.

Comment: Note also that the server does not know what kind of request a client will send. It can thus not selectively enable or disable support for early data based on the type of the future request. At most it could reject a request if 0-RTT is used with a non-idempotent requests after it has received the request.